# How can I get Interfaces and method body with SimpleElementVisitor in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation

Im doing some code generation for my Flutter project. I basically want to rebuild a whole class with source_gen. I am using the SimpleElementVisitor to get most of the data. I had no issues getting field, field types, method names and the class name.

This is e.g. how I get my class name:

```
@override
  void visitConstructorElement(ConstructorElement element) {
    final returnType = element.returnType.toString();
    className = returnType.replaceFirst('*', ''); 
  }
```

I thought I could get my first interface name e.g. like this.

```
@override
  void visitClassElement(ClassElement element) {
    firstInterfaceName = element.interfaces.first;
  }
```

But somehow the visitClassElement function is not accessed at all I feel like. Even print statements in it are not executed. The other functions work fine.

Also how can I get a method body? Pls don't just post any ChatGPT answers. I tried that already.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

your **visitClassElement** method does not work because there is not a single **ClassElement** in the list of elements that the **ElementVisitor** should iterate over. But there are methods, fields and a constructor for which the corresponding methods **visitMethodElement**, **visitFieldElement**, **visitConstructorElement** are triggered.

But if you ask your **ElementVisitor** to iterate over the children of **CompilationUnitElement**, which you can get from buildStep, then among its children there is a **ClassElement** for which the **visitClassElement** method will certainly be called.
Here is a code example that will allow the **visitClassElement** method to be called -

```
@override
FutureOr<void> build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
  var visitor = ModelVisitor();
  final LibraryElement library = await buildStep.resolver.libraryFor(buildStep.inputId, allowSyntaxErrors: true);

  List<CompilationUnitElement> units = library.units;
  for (var unit in units) {
    unit.visitChildren(visitor);
  }
}
```